# unittest housekeeping in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, fixtures

I've got a `unittest` test file containing four test classes each of which is responsible for running tests on one specific class. Each test class makes us of exactly the same `set-up` and `teardown` methods. The `set-up` method is relatively large, initiating about 20 different variables, while the `teardown` method simply resets these twenty variables to their initial state.

Up to now I have been putting the twenty variables in each of the four setUp classes. This works, but is not very easily maintained; if I decide to change one variable, I must change it in all four setUp methods. My search for a more elegant solution has failed however. Ideally I'd just like to enter my twenty variables once, call them up in each of my four `setup` methods, then tear them down after each of my test methods. With this end in mind I tried putting the variables in a separate module and importing this in each setUp, but of course the variables are then only available in the setup method (plus, though I couldn't put my finger on the exact reasons, this felt like a potentially problem-prone way of doing it

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Test_Books(TestCase):
    def setup():
        # a quick and easy way of making my variables available at the class level
        # without typing them all in

    def test_method_1(self):
        # setup variables available here in their original state
        # ... mess about with the variables ...
        # reset variables to original state

    def test_method_2(self):
        # setup variables available here in their original state
        # etc...

    def teardown(self):
        # reset variables to original state without having to type them all in



class Books():
    def method_1(self):
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Show actual code, not a comment that says what you're doing instead of showing what your doing when that exact code is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to put the twenty variables into a separate class, set the values in the class's `__init__` and then access the data as class.variable, thus the only place to set the variable s in the `__init__` and the code s not duplicated.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        data.x= ...
        data.y = ....

class Test_Books(TestCase):
    def setup():
        self.data = Data()

    def test_method_1(self):
       value = self.data.x   # get the data from the variable
```

This solution makes more sense if the twenty pieces of data are related to each other. Also if you have twenty pieces of data I would expect them to be related and so they should be combined in the real code not just in test.

Comment: Have selected this as my answer, since it is closer to what I was hoping to be able to do, and dispenses with the need to subclass TestCase. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make the 4 test classes each a subclass of one base test class which itself is a subclass of TestCase. Then put setip and teardown in the base class and the rest in the others.

e.g.

```
class AbstractBookTest(TestCase):
   def setup():
      ...

class Test_Book1(AbstractBookTest):
   def test_method_1(self):
     ...
```

An alternative is just to make one class not the four you have which seems to be a bit more logical here unless you give a reason for the split.

Comment: >>>An alternative is just to make one class not the four you have...  I suppose I arranged it like this because it seemed sensible to have one test class for every class I was testing, I take your point thought that this isn't strictly necessary, particularly since the classes are actual pretty small. I like your first idea as well, so will give both a go.

Comment: @PaulPatterson - I misread your question I thought you were just testing one class - forget this part of the answer.

Comment: No worries. I've done the subclassing thing and it works nicely. thanks!